# Displaying gif VideoClips on a half circle path with moviepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am trying to compose a collection of about 6 to 7 gif aniated clips on top of a base video. These animated icons are shown on along a half circle at the center of the video. I am figuring out the best way to write this logic, but stuck at this for a while. Any help is much appreciated.

```
positions = [
            [(200,200)], 
            [(200,300)],
            [(200,400)],
            [(200,500)],
            [(200,600)],
            [(200,700)],
            [(200,800)],
            [(200,900)],
            [(200,1000)]
            
            ]
    
clip = (VideoFileClip(f"{DIRECTORY+wd}.gif")
                .set_start(0)
                .set_duration(video_clip.duration)
                .set_position(positions[l]))
clips.append(clip)

        
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clips[i] for i in range(len(clips))])
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do but `concatenate_videoclips( [clips[i] for i in range(len(clips))] )` should mean the same as `concatenate_videoclips( clips )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you try to do but it should be rather

```
positions = [
    (200, 200), 
    (200, 300),
    (200, 400),
    (200, 500),
    (200, 600),
    (200, 700),
    (200, 800),
    (200, 900),
    (200, 1000)
]
    
clips = []

for pos in positions:
    clip = (VideoFileClip(f"{DIRECTORY+wd}.gif")
                .set_start(0)
                .set_duration(video_clip.duration)
                .set_position(pos))
    clips.append(clip)
        
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
```

---

**EDIT:**

And if you want to draw on circle path then you may need to use `sin()`, `cos()` to calculate positions.

I used `matplotlib` to display positions.

It calculates 36 positions (every 10 degrees) for circle with radius 10, and center (50,50)

```
from math import sin, cos, radians

positions = []

r = 10
center_x = 50
center_y = 50

for angle in range(0, 360, 10):
    x = center_x + sin(radians(angle)) * r
    y = center_y + cos(radians(angle)) * r
    positions.append( (x, y) )

# ---

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_x = [pos[0] for pos in positions]
data_y = [pos[1] for pos in positions]

plt.scatter(data_x, data_y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I am trying to show all gif clips on an elipse path. like not in a straight line.

Comment: you may need `sin()`, `cos()` to calculate positions on elipse

Comment: I added example code to calculate positions on circle.